# Get immediate parent context from foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I have a base view-model and a submodel inside that. This submodel, in turn, has a few arrays and a method `testFunction`. I am iterating over the arrays present inside the sub model. Inside that iteration in HTML, I need to refer to the method in the sub model which is the immediate parent. How can I achieve this? How can I reference the immediate parent context from inside a foreach block? I have created a fiddle.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whQmX/25/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$parents[1].testFunction`

You may use one of the following based on your view model hierarchy :

**$root :** This points to the main view model object in the root context.The top most parent context.

**$parents array :** This is an array which contains all your view models.

**$parents[0]** : The parent view model context.(also it’s the same as $parent)

**$parents[1]:** The second parent view model context.(grand parent)

**$parents[2]:** The third parent view model context . (great-grand parent)

And so on....